# Resizing Div width to fit to its child control

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to apply jQuery resizable and draggable on my aspx page. Most of the things are in order except that the **resizable handles are getting placed at different positions on the controls** i.e

> for a label(DynamicControlABC) it is getting shown at the center of
>   the label whereas for the textbox(DynamicControlTextbox1) its getting
>   shown approx 3px outside the se corner.

If I try to reposition the handle according to the textbox then the handle moves more towards the center of the Label and vice versa
(I would have posted a screenshot but atleast 10 reputation points needed to post an image :( ). **I viewed the page on both IE10 and Firefox** and both yield the same result.

**My Code is below:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css_custom/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#btnEdit").click(function (e) {
                SetButtonText();
                ToggleEditMode();
            });

        function SetButtonText() {
            $('#btnEdit').val(function (i, text) {
                return text === "Edit" ? "Editing" : "Edit";
            });
        }

        function ToggleEditMode() {
            if ($("#btnEdit").val() != "Edit") {
                $("*").filter("[id^=DynamicControl]"), function () {
                    $(this).resizable().parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({ opacity: .45, cancel: "null" });
                };
            }
            else {
                $("*").resizable({ cancel: "*" }).draggable({ cancel: "*" });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="MyForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Label Text="ABCDEFGH" runat="server" ID="DynamicControlABC"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DynamicControlTextbox1" Text="Text1"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I am new to asking questions here so please let me know if I am missing out something.

This is what I did in the jQuery-UI.js. The following code already existed

```
if(this.element[0].nodeName.match(/canvas|textarea|input|select|button|img/i)) {

        //Create a wrapper element and set the wrapper to the new current internal element
        this.element.wrap(
            $("<div class='ui-wrapper' style='overflow: hidden;'></div>").css({
                position: this.element.css("position"),
                width: this.element.outerWidth(),
                height: this.element.outerHeight() ,
                top: this.element.css("top") ,
                left: this.element.css("left")
            })
        );
```

and I added this for a label:-

```
 else if(this.element[0].nodeName.match(/label|span|div/i)) {

        this.element.wrap(
            $("<div class='ui-wrapper' style='overflow: hidden;'></div>").css({
                position: this.element.css("position"),
                width: this.element.outerWidth() + 7,
                height: this.element.outerHeight() + 3,
                top: this.element.css("top") ,
                left: this.element.css("left") 
            })
        );
```

Now the handles are coming up fine on the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason the resizable handles are getting placed weirdly is I think you're using the universal selector ("*") so it targets anything, its not that bad to use this selector but if your building an app its quite expensive to use this on filtering the DOM

Here take a look what i did, on your code

there was some minor refactoring  and removing ( you can put back your method whatever you like)

im not sure why your using cancel instead of draggable disable (let me know if this is intended)

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

       $("#btnEdit").click(function () {  
             resizableMode();
       });


        function resizableMode() {

            //cache selectors
            var $elem = $('[id^=DynamicControl]'); 
            var $editBtn = $("#btnEdit");

            //toggleText button
            $editBtn.val(function (i, text) {
                return text === "Edit" ? "Editing" : "Edit";
            }); 

            //set resizable to textbox
            $elem.resizable(); 

            //set states
            if ($editBtn.val() !== "Edit") {
                 $elem.resizable('enable')
                      .parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({ opacity: 0.45 , disabled:false }); 
            } else { 
                $elem.resizable('disable')
                     .parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({ disabled: true });
            }
        }

});
```

see output

http://jsbin.com/sowah/1
(there is slight css changes)

you can edit it here
http://jsbin.com/sowah/1/edit

Comment: 1. Thanks a lot for pointing out about the ("*") selector, your method is much more cost effective. 2. Yeah the cancel was intended because until I put in the cancel:"null" none of the controls are getting dragged (tried using your code also but it doesn't work as far as draggable is concerned) 3.Now the  problem is If you apply resizable to the Label field (requires editing in the jQuery-ui.js) then the draggable handle will appear somewhere in the middle of the label. Maybe I need to use a separate set of css for them, will let you know after I try it. –

Comment: It worked!!!...edited the jQuery-ui.js and added a seperate class for the label, But the control positions are going haywire when I click on the Edit button...I know it is because of the wrapper divs and handles being added to the controls...Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: hmm its hard to understand whats happening on your side would u mind add your updated code on your post, anyway what i understand is your having problem with the dragging handle, you can control that with CSS  and its always inside and visible when draggable is enabled , check  .ui-wrapper

Comment: I have added the changes done for the label in the edit. basically tinkered with the jQuery-UI.css to set the CSS of the ui-wrapper. Is this the way to go? I will need to do the same thing for my Buttons and maybe later on for other controls?